# 'spring.thymeleaf.servlet.content-type' is an unknown property

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm running my first spring project, and I' m using sts as ide, I want to use Thymeleaf for the page templates, but the th:href link does not work as link but plain text, but I can't find the page I want and can't redirect to thymeleaf page:

```
#==================================
# = JSP Configuration
#==================================
#spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
#spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
#
#==================================
# = Thymeleaf configurations
#==================================
#spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.servlet.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
server.servlet.context-path=/
#
#==================================
# = Datasource configuration
#==================================
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
#spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/siw
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
#
#==================================
# = Webserver configuration
#==================================
server.port= 8080 
#
#==================================
# = Misc configuration
#==================================
spring.messages.basename=messages/validation
#
#==================================
# = Security configuration
#==================================
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration
spring.security.user.name=paolo
spring.security.user.password=paolo
```

this is the Pom I'm using to find and resolve the libraries dependency with maven:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>it.uniroma3</groupId>
    <artifactId>progettoSIW</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>progettoSIW</name>
    <description>project for SIW</description>

    <!--    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> 
    </parent>
    -->

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

How can I fix it, I use in the html this to specify the use of thymeleaf:
`xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"`

P.S. If I use the .../resource/templates as location for index, I can't find it; I need to put it on .../resouces/static

Answer (score 0):

add th:ref as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body><div class="starter-template">
    <h1>Spring Boot Web Thymeleaf Example</h1>
    <h2>
        <span th:text="'Message: ' + ${message}"></span>
        <a th:href="@{${link}}">view</a>
       <!-- <span th:link="${link}" th:text="${link}"></span>-->
    </h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please refer working code for this in [here](https://gitlab.com/supun/spring-boot-app)

And about your other question, setting custom template location, you need to modify the application.properties file like this

```
spring.thymeleaf.check-template=true
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/static/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
```

Comment: this haven't solve my problem and if the page is in static is not read

Comment: Please see the modified answer